# TextBox readline with button command

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

I'm just trying to figure out how I can enter a number into a TextBox and click a button and make the number go into another TextBox. I know I need to make a double value like price and make it equal to zero. I'm just wondering how I would make the button control the first TextBox.

```
private void DepositTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string deposits = Console.ReadLine();
        double deposit = double.Parse(deposits);
        deposit += balance;
    }

    private void WithdrawTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string withdraws = Console.ReadLine();
        double withdraw = double.Parse(withdraws);
        withdraw += balance;
    }
```

This is my code but when I run it as soon as I put a number or letter in the TextBox, it says value cannot be null, parameter name: value.

Comment: On your button click event, `Textbox1.Text = Textbox2.Text`

Comment: Yes button I am going to enter the number into the first TextBox and have it actively display it in the second. Would Textbox1.Text = Textbox2.Text work?

Comment: I tried that code and it didn't even let me enter a value into the TextBox.

Comment: Something doesn't looks good. Why are you reading a line from the `Console` if you're working with WinForms? For getting the text to parse, you can simply get the `Text` property from the deposit TextBox, parse, then place the value on the Text property on the withdraw TextBox.

Comment: I'm not moving from the deposit to the withdraw, they each do a separate thing, the deposit box adds a value to my third textbox, the withdraw box takes away a value from the third text box.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you speak of a Button Click but your code sample shows a TextChanged event?

Sounds like you should probably create a form-level property to the store the total balance and manipulate that.

In your ButtonClick events, Convert the textbox.Text to a numeric type and then perform the appropriate mathmatical operation on the total balance.

Then simply just display that balance property in the other textbox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private double balance;

    private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value = Convert.ToDouble(txtDeposit.Text);
        balance += value;

        txtBalance.Text = balance.ToString();
    }

    private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value = Convert.ToDouble(txtWithdraw.Text);
        balance -= value;

        txtBalance.Text = balance.ToString();
    }
}
```